# Changing advanced options in PowerPoint with VBScript

Tags: vba, vbscript, powerpoint

I am writing a VBS script which copies chosen pictures from the folder where the script is placed to newly created PowerPoint document, adds some comments to each slide and saves the document in the same directory. The problem that I'm facing is a size of .pptx file which very often exceeds 500MB. 
PowerPoint (2013) has built-in option to "Discard editing data" in Advanced Option menu which lowers the resolution of all images in the document to wish value (220 ppi in my case). 
Is there an option to access related checkbox with VBSript? I was searching hard to find information how to enable this option via scripting but haven't found anything useful.

I would be much grateful for your help!

Comment: Record a macro doing it then adapt it to VBScript. Alt + T, M, R. Repeat to stop recording. To view code Alt + F11. Remember in VBScript have to use `CreateObject()` not `set x = New Object` and replace constants with their values.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Please correct me if I am wrong but macro recording is not possible in PP since 2010 version and I don't have access to older versions than 2013 (so shortcut key does not work).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/options-object-powerpoint With COM there vwill be an application object. If relevant there will be a Options property holding something (in PPT's case an options object. You can view the object model Alt + F11, F2.

Comment: Here's some background on COM objects https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/using-standard-objects

Comment: Also pptx, docX, etc are zip files. (doc, xls, etc are structured storage files). Rename them to zip to look inside their file structure with explorer.

Comment: @P_M You're correct; there's no longer a macro recorder in PPT and even if there were, it wouldn't record this particular feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that's accessible via the PPT object model, but since you're using VBS and not VBA from within PPT, you can probably make a few registry settings before launching PowerPoint.

To work out the needed settings, open REGEDIT and navigate to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\PowerPoint\Options
```

Note:  15.0 is the version to use for PPT 2013. PPT 2016 is 16.0, 2010 is 14.0 and so on, skipping 13.0

Leave REGEDIT open while you change the PPT settings you're after; after each change, switch to REGEDIT and hit F5 to refresh. Any settings that change or are newly added are the ones you're after.

To get you started, the setting for automatically compressing pictures is a DWORD:

```
AutomaticPictureCompressionDefault
```

Comment: @GeertBellekens As I said, this particular feature is NOT in the object model. If it were, there'd likely be no problem accessing it from VBS.